# Set-ADAccountPassword - The operation failed because of a bad parameter

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

I am writing a script to reset a ADusers password, through PowerShell

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity TestA -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force)
```

when I run the above script I get the below
[image]

Any ideas on what could be causing this

I have tried changing the password, to see if it was the criteria that was affecting it. all is fine on that front.

I have checked the users -Identity and used other options and still no change

Comment: Looks like it might not be able to resolve `TestA`. Does `Get-ADUser -Identity TestA` show you the expected user account object?

Comment: It does indeed, i've just ran it to make sure and it pulls back the right account. I did also try "ObjectGUID" and "DistinguishedName" but get the same result

Comment: Is the powershell session running as an account with permissions to change an AD user's password ? Can you try targeting a different Domain Controller with `-Server` ?

Comment: Yeah, it is its an account with full access so no challenge with it on that side, unless there is a specific one for "Set-ADAccountPassword" same thing even when using -sever

Comment: If you pull up the user in the Active Directory Users and Computers, are you able to reset their password from that interface? Do you know the existing password? If so you could try changing the password by providing the old and new passwords rather than resetting the password. This would help determine if the issue is related to the account of your ability to reset the password for the account.

Comment: I am able to reset their password through Active Directory Users and Computers. Same error occurs when using old and new passwords.

Comment: Are you sure the new password meets the password complexity rules of your AD environment?

Comment: @Tester123 Your codes are working fine in my environment. Maybe some permission issue is with your AD server.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look through our permissions to see what could be stopping it. I have found another solution using 'dsmod'